# Iterating over file locations in a file to check of they exist

Tags: bash, grep, iteration

I am writing this command in bash to check for files in a system. The files locations are written in "New.txt":

```
for files in $(grep "spider" "New.txt"); do if test -e "$files"; then echo $files; else echo "NOT $files"; fi; done

Output: 
NOT C:/USERS/IBRAHIM/my_spider.csv
NOT C:/USERS/IBRAHIM/spider.txt
C:/USERS/IBRAHIM/newspider.txt
```

for some reason it is only taking the last occurrence in the file, although "spider.txt" is also found. If I try to switch the last 2 lines in New.txt it will take the last occurence only which is in this case "spider.txt". Can somebody please help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the content of the file "New.txt" too.

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Can you check whether the `New.txt` text file endlines are (Linux-compliant) LineFeeds, not CarriageReturn+LineFeed? (see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Issues_with_different_newline_formats) for details)

Comment: Thanks ErikMd you were right I tried it on Linux  and it worked. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` this way will not work if any path contains spaces.

I would suggest using the Bash built-in `readarray` to load your "New.txt" into an array, and iterating over that.

```sh
readarray -t my_list < <(grep -q 'spider' "New.txt")

for file in "${my_list[@]}"; do 
    if [ -e "$file" ]; then
        echo "$file"
    else
        echo "NOT $file"
    fi
done
```

An alternative to using `grep` would be to use Bash regular expressions:

```sh
readarray -t my_list < "New.txt"

for file in "${my_list[@]}"; do 
    [[ "$file" =~ spider ]] || continue
    if [ -e "$file" ]; then
        echo "$file"
    else
        echo "NOT $file"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you request.

You want to loop throw a list of files exist in a file and check the existing of each file.

Here is an example , `spider.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage(){
    echo "./program file pattern"
}

function process(){
    [ ! -f $1 ] && echo "Main file("$1") not found !" && exit 1
    # Get all lines with the pattern $2 and check if it is actually a file
    for file in $(grep $2 $1); do
        [ -f $file ] && echo "$file" || echo "NOT $file"
    done
}

[ $# -ne 2 ] && usage || process $1 $2;
```

Simple usage:

Create 2 existing spider files, 1 non existing spider file, 1 existing non-spider file and one non-existing non-spider file

```
$ touch spiderfiles.txt spider_file{1,2}.txt other_file.txt
$ echo $(realpath spider_file1.txt) >> spiderfiles.txt
$ echo $(realpath spider_file2.txt) >> spiderfiles.txt
$ echo $(realpath other_file.txt) >> spiderfiles.txt
$ echo "/non/existing/spider_file.txt" >> spiderfiles.txt
$ echo "/non/existing/file.txt" >> spiderfiles.txt
```

How to use the script:

*First argument:* the file containing the files paths

*Second argument:* the pattern to look for

```
./spider.sh spiderfiles.txt spider
```

Result as expected:

```
/home/talel/Documents/Stackoverflow/files/spider_file1.txt
/home/talel/Documents/Stackoverflow/files/spider_file2.txt
NOT /non/existing/spider_file.txt
```